# Как получить в OnItemClickListener информацию которая есть в выбранном view?

Tags: android, listview

В списке есть TextView, в котором записан номер телефона, как мне при нажатии на View элемент списка получить этот TextView или данные из него.

Comment: Нужно больше информации о реализации списка (примеры кода), без неё посоветовать конкретное решение сложно.

Comment: Пункт списка это Activity, а потом я их добавляю в ListView через layoutInflater

Comment: Вот как выглядит сам элемент списка
[Item viev](https://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=0680d5b3c9ee7a256bbebd2c7692817e)
А так он добавляется на activity [ссылка](https://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=6b701823808def5b445a575d9f6570ba)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь может быть ответ на ваш вопрос: [StartAndroid. Урок 44. События в ListView](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/85-urok-44-sobytija-v-listview.html)

> OnItemClickListener – обрабатывает нажатие на пункт списка
>
> Предоставляет нам метод onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id), где 
>   view – это нажатый пункт, в нашем случае – TextView из android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1

Соответственно, так можно получить TextView, а для получения телефона из него попробуйте использовать view.Text.